# Elasticsearch Nest - simple query with multiple filters

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to do a simple query where I want to:

```
select * from POC where Account_No = [accountno] and BUSINESS_UNIT = [business_unit]
```

below is what I have with no luck.  Any ideas?

```
var filters = new List<FilterContainer>();

filters.Add(new FilterDescriptor<poc>().Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Term(i => i.Account_No, txtAccount.Text))));
filters.Add(new FilterDescriptor<poc>().Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Term(i => i.BUSINESS_UNIT, txtBU.Text))));

var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<poc>();
// Filter with AND operator
searchDescriptor.Filter(f => f.And(filters.ToArray()));

var r = client.Search<poc>(searchDescriptor);
```

**Update**

The second filter does not appear to work.
When I run this I get no records which I am not sure.  I see it when I run the record when I look at the account query

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "BUSINESS_UNIT": "CSPCN"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want:

```
FilterContainer filter = null;

filter &= Filter<poc>.Term(i => i.Account_No, txtAccount.Text);
filter &= Filter<poc>.Term(i => i.BUSINESS_UNIT, txtBU.Text);

var r = client.Search<poc>(sd => sd.Filter(f => filter));
```

Comment: I found out that Business unit should be lowercase.  thanks for your response

Comment: Ah, very good. Sounds like you're using the standard analyzer then. You can specify a schema for your type and use a different analyzer which can be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I change the filter to use Match instead of Term and it seemed to work.

I am not sure why this is the case, but when I do a search using Business_Unit using Term, even by itself, it doesn't return any results.

```
var filters = new List<FilterContainer>();

filters.Add(new FilterDescriptor<poc>().Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Query(q => q.Wildcard(z => z.Account_No, txtAccount.Text + "*")))));
filters.Add(new FilterDescriptor<poc>().Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Query(q => q.Match(mat => mat.OnField(z => z.BUSINESS_UNIT).Query(txtBU.Text))))));

var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<poc>();
// Filter with AND operator
searchDescriptor.Filter(f => f.And(filters.ToArray()));

var r = client.Search<poc>(searchDescriptor);
```

**Update**

I was able to using match, but I just had to make the value lowercase, which explains why it didnt return any results.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "BUSINESS_UNIT": "cspcn"
    }
  }
}
```